# Unable to detect USB->Serial adapter on Lumia 950 in UWP

Tags: c#, serial-port, win-universal-app

I am trying to test out connecting to a USB-Serial device on a Lumia 950 Windows 10 phone in a UWP. I have a few lines of code to list the USB Serial devices connected to the device. On the PC this works when the USB-> Serial device is connected but when I run it on the phone, nothing is detected. Do I need to enable this functionality some how on the phone? Here is the UWP code.

In the Package,appxmanifest I have the following:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

In the Code behind I have a button click event that does the following:

```
  string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
  DeviceInformationCollection deviceInformation = 
           await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

  foreach (var i in deviceInformation)
  {
    CommPorts.Add( i.Name +" - " + i.Id );
  }
```

The CommPorts is an ObservableCollection as follows:

```
  public ObservableCollection<string> CommPorts { get; set; }
```

On the PC I get these devices listed:

- ABACUS ELECTRICS Optical Probe - \\?\FTDIBUS#VID_0403+PID_F458+AE000000A#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
- TEST-WORK001 - \\?\ACPI#PNP0501#1#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}

On the Phone I get:

- Lumia 950 - \\?\ACPI#QCOM2424#2#{...}
- Lumia 950 - \\?\ACPI#QCOM2424#8#{...}

It doesn't change if I remove the USB Serial device. Any ideas on what I need to do to get this working on the phone? Do I need special drivers?

Comment: It could be that the FTDI chipset is not supported on Mobile. Is there a list somewhere of what serial chipsets are supported on mobile? What serial device does an Arduino board have?

Comment: I just had a similar experience. It would be nice to find a compatible one.